# Resetting TIME column when AMT > 0

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
ID  TIME  AMT
1    0    50
1    1    0
1    2    0
1    3    0
1    4    0
1    4    50
1    5    0
1    7    0
1    9    0
1    10   0
1    10   50
```

The `TIME` column in the above data frame is continuous. I want to add another time column that resets time from zero when `AMT>0`. So, my output data frame should look like this:

```
    ID  TIME  AMT  TIME2
    1    0    50    0
    1    1    0     1 
    1    2    0     2 
    1    3    0     3 
    1    4    0     4
    1    4    50    0
    1    5    0     1
    1    7    0     3
    1    9    0     5
    1    10   0     6
    1    10   50    0
```

This is basically achieved by subtracting the `TIME` from a  "fixed" reference `TIME`  when `AMT>0` (For example; the reference time for the second `AMT>0` is 4. So, the `TIME2` is calculated by subtracting `5-4=1` ;`7-4=3`; `9-4=5` etc. How can I do this automatically in R.

Comment: @agstudy why did you add [tag:data.table] here? Didn't see OP mentioning it anywhere. Tags are set per question not per answer.

Comment: David Arenburg for some reasons : I know that data.table maintainers (at least @Arun)  will control data.table answers, the question have some grouping feature so data.table is a natural candidate , I think also the more you have tags the better you can reach this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `data.table` solution :

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DT)[,TIME2 := TIME-TIME[1],cumsum(AMT>0)]

#      ID TIME AMT TIME2
# 1:   1    0  50     0
# 2:   1    1   0     1
# 3:   1    2   0     2
# 4:   1    3   0     3
# 5:   1    4   0     4
# 6:   1    4  50     0
# 7:   1    5   0     1
# 8:   1    7   0     3
# 9:   1    9   0     5
# 10:  1   10   0     6
# 11:  1   10  50     0
```

Comment: @DavidArenburg There is no need to include ID in my case. It work perfectly fine with multiple IDs. Thank you both for the solutions. They made my life easy!

Answer (score 4):

Was originally posting the same answer as @agstudy, so here's alternatively a possible base R solution

```
with(df, ave(TIME, cumsum(AMT > 0L), ID, FUN = function(x) x - x[1L]))
## [1] 0 1 2 3 4 0 1 3 5 6 0
```

Or

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(cumsum(AMT > 0), ID) %>%
  mutate(TIME2 = TIME - first(TIME))
```

Comment: Another option is `library(zoo); with(df, TIME-na.locf(NA^(!AMT) * TIME))`

Comment: @akrun, how probable is that you will remember the logic behind that code and what it actually does months after writing it? 

Comment: @Arun I agree that it is not easy to understand.  That's the reason I put it as a comment :-)